# How to change the text in renderers.ph in the breadcrumbs, moodle 2.7?

Tags: navbar, moodle, breadcrumbs

I am trying to change the text of home to a fontAwesome icon in the breadcrumbs of the navbar (Moodle 2.7).

I overrode the core_render.php using a file from the Shoelace theme.

I added a line just after the breadcrumbs array is initialized to change `$breadcrumbs[0]`; that just did half of the work. The icon replaced the text but the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag isn't what I expect; it follows the navigation, not the URL of home.

I don't understand where this link is made. How can I use the fontAwesome icon while keeping the home URL?

Here's the code:

```
class theme_ubo_core_renderer extends theme_bootstrapbase_core_renderer {
    /*
     * This renders the navbar.
     * Uses bootstrap compatible html.
     */
    public function navbar() {
        $items = $this->page->navbar->get_items();
        if (right_to_left()) {
            $dividericon = 'fa-angle-left';
        } else {
            $dividericon = 'fa-angle-right';
        }
        $divider = html_writer::tag('span', html_writer::start_tag('i', array('class' => 'fa '. $dividericon .' fa-lg')) .
                        html_writer::end_tag('i'), array('class' => 'divider'));
        $breadcrumbs = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $item->hideicon = true;
            $breadcrumbs[] = $this->render($item);
        }

        //Change the first entry

        $breadcrumbs[0]='<a href=""><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></a>';


        $list_items = html_writer::start_tag('li') . implode("$divider" . html_writer::end_tag('li') .
                        html_writer::start_tag('li'), $breadcrumbs) . html_writer::end_tag('li');
        $title = html_writer::tag('span', get_string('pagepath'), array('class' => 'accesshide'));
        return $title . html_writer::tag('ul', "$list_items", array('class' => 'breadcrumb'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
$breadcrumbs[] = $this->render($item);
```

will calls the function [render_navigation_node($item)](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lib/outputrenderers.php#L3124) (I think - I haven't double-checked)

That function takes each item in the breadcrumb and turns it from a navigation_node instance into a string.

If you just want force the first item to be a link to 'home', with your chosen icon, you can probably get away with:

```
$breadcrumbs[0] = html_writer::link(new moodle_url('/'), html_writer::tag('i', '', array('class' => 'fa fa-home fa-2x')));
```

An alternative would be to see if you can change the 'content' of the first $item in the $items array to be the icon you want, before you loop through and call render() on each item.

Comment: Thanks! That works like I want. The other was to change the string in the lang folder but I prefer your solution which keeps all in the same place.